# Ensure pyinstaller run with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I've a Python project, run it on Ubuntu 18.04 server machine (in VBox). I've created 2 venvs:

```
* virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv27
* virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv36
```

Start venv27 with command:

```
source path/to/my/venv/python/venvs/venv27/bin/activate
```

After venv starts to run I've installed PyInstaller with:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Generation process was sucesfully done, but during the generation process I've seen this message:

```
46 INFO: Python: 3.6.8
```

Does it means that PyInstaller run with Python 3.6 however I run PyInstaller in venv where python version is 2.7?
I would like just be ensure that my compressed python code use python 2.7?

Thanks for your help and answer!

---

I've delete all created venvs and start it again. Here is the results:[image]

Activate the new venv27:
[image]

Installed again PyInstaller:
[image]

...and now the message was:
[image]

Currently I've not created venv36 only venv27, so probably problem could be, but I am not sure that venv36 was active, but I didn't know that.

Thank you Gantemens for your help. My last question is: how can I accept your answer/suggestion because it looks like both comment were right.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't activate the Python 3.6 venv first?

Comment: That does mean PyInstaller was run with Python 3.6. I tried replicating what you did and I got messages saying the correct Python versions depending on which virtualenv I used. Maybe it wasn't really run in a 2.7 virtualenv?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: well! I am using Ubuntu 18.04 server, where python 2.7 and python 3.6 installed automatically. If I just typing: python --version I got that python 2.7 and if I run: python3 --version got that python vesion is 3.6. So I am not sure what you mean: activate Python 3.6.
That's the reason why I the '-p' flag when I've created the different venvs.

Comment: @DanGetz: well! I don't know. I did how I wrote down...so I don't understand what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Let me share my experiences and I would like to ask from @AlastairMcCormack and Dan Getz...
I've created 2 venvs with different Python version. One for 2.7 and one for 3.6. start and stop them. If active one venv - at the same of course I am running only one venv - python --version send beck the right version. 
If I start the version 2.7 venv, run pyinstaller just couple times, then deactivate the venv and start the other, in the new 3.6 version user venv use python 2.7 for pyinstaller...I don't understand why so I'm just wondering on that...

Comment: @aBanhidy I don't know...I tried to do the same on my machine (similar but not identical versions) and did not see the same issue. Is this all in the same terminal window?

Comment: Yes it is...I do everything in the same window, under the same session. My other/new experiences if create a venv and not install for example PyInstaller but it is already installed in the main, system python area that will be used. I think, but I don't know how could make some confusion because probably Python venv 2.7 version start to use a 3rd party package from Python 3.6. I'm not sure on it is just an imagination...